# Browser page keeps refreshing when testing Backbone views with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine

Running the following Jasmine test(1), the test is successfully performed but I face the recursive loading of the main test page.

Here is my test (1) and here the module on which I am running the test (2):

Any ideas? How can I fix the issue?

P.S.:
The issue regard just Chrome and Safari Browser.
Here is an example: jsfiddle.net/shioyama/EXvZY

---

(1)

```
describe('When Submit button handler fired', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        spyOn(MyView.prototype, 'submitForm');
        this.view = new MyView();
        this.view.render();
        this.view.$el.find('form').submit();
    });

    it('submitForm should be called', function () {
        expect(MyView.prototype.submitForm).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

---

(2)

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'submit form' : 'submitForm'
    },

    submitForm: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // some code
    }
});
```

Comment: I've created a jsfiddle for this here: http://jsfiddle.net/shioyama/EXvZY/8/ . The test passes and I don't see any recursive loading, but maybe I don't know quite what to look for. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Sorry this is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/shioyama/EXvZY/

Comment: @shioyama, I thank you for having created the jsfiddle. Did you understand what I mean?

Comment: No unfortunately I don't see what you're talking about. Does it show up in the jsfiddle?

Comment: @shioyama your http://jsfiddle.net/shioyama/EXvZY/ is a good example. Anyway, the problem regards only Chrome and Safari. Try to run load http://jsfiddle.net/shioyama/EXvZY/ in Chrome or Safari and you will see the issue.

Comment: oh I see, I'm using firefox which would explain why I don't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone uses *delegate events*, which are bound when the view is created. Your view.el does not contain a form when it is created, but instead you're creating one in the render method. That's why the submit delegate event does not get bound, and instead you're submitting the form on the page. That form submit goes to the same URL, which triggers the Jasmine suite to be run again, resulting in a loop.

If you modify your code a bit, you'll find that this version works, as the *<form>* element exists before the view is generated.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'submit form' : 'submitForm'
    },

    submitForm: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // some code
    }
});

//start test runner right after we're done defining our tests in this script
window.setTimeout( function(){
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.TrivialReporter());
    jasmine.getEnv().execute();
}, 0 );

//TESTS GO HERE
describe('When Submit button handler fired', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        spyOn(MyView.prototype, 'submitForm').andCallThrough();
        this.view = new MyView({
            el: $('<div><form><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form></div>')
        });
        this.view.$el.find('form').submit();
    });

    it('submitForm should be called', function () {
        expect(MyView.prototype.submitForm).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});​
```

​

Comment: Thanks for you answer. your explanation is very clear. Anyway if I create `this.view` without calling `render` the `MyView.prototype.submitForm`  is not called when I perform the test `this.view.$el.find('form').submit();` or `this.view.$el.submit();`. Any ideas?

Comment: Here is the jsfidlle using your suggestion http://jsfiddle.net/EXvZY/19/ which does not work. Please correct me if I missed something!

Comment: Two things: #1: Delegate events use a selector, so they won't be bound to the root node - I added a div as a container & #2: You add a spy, but don't allow the call to propagate down to the spied element, which means that the submit handler will never return false - need to add .andCallThrough().

Comment: Can you please award the bounty now? ;)