# Backbone form submission refreshes page in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

Similar issue to this one: [Browser page keeps refreshing when testing Backbone views with Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986605/browser-page-keeps-refreshing-when-testing-backbone-views-with-jasmine). 
The submission of my Bootstrap-modal form fails and refreshes the page in Chrome. I understand the solution found in the link, but I don't know how to make it work for Bootstrap forms. Any help?

```
window.FormPopup = Backbone.View.extend({
template: _.template($('#popup-template').html()),

events: {
    "click .sector-label" : "edit",
    "keypress .sector-label-edit input" : "setLabel"
},

render: function() {
    var view = this;

    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    this.$el.modal({
        backdrop: false
    });
    this.$el.on("hidden", function() {
        view.remove();
    });

    this.$el.find("form").submit(function() {
        $(this).find("input:text").each(function() {
            var label = $(this).val();
            if (label.length > 0)
                view.model.addChild(label);
        });
        view.$el.modal("hide");
    });
},

edit: function() {
    this.$el.addClass("edit");
    this.$el.find(".sector-label-edit input").focus();
},

setLabel: function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 13)
        return;
    var newLabel = this.$el.find(".sector-label-edit input").val();
    this.model.set("label", newLabel);
    this.$el.find(".sector-label h3").html(newLabel);
    this.$el.removeClass("edit");
},
});
```

Comment: Are you submitting the form with AJAX? Saving a model? You need to prevent the default browser submit and handle it yourself. (Also, why aren't you binding that form submit in the `events` hash?)

Comment: checkout http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/ to prevent your default submit event.